# Case insensitive sorting with sort(list, key=str.lower)

Tags: python, sorting, case-insensitive

I have a module designed to allow users to enter 10 words, then alphabetize them, and display them. Just using the sort functions puts capitalized words first, so i used sort(list, key=str.lower) but the output is still incorrect. Code, and error, below:

```
def words_function():

    words = [input("Enter 10 words, one at a time: ") for i in range(10)]
    sorted(words, key=str.lower)
    print("Alphabetized, your words are: ", words)

    userSearch = input("What word would you like to search for?")

    if userSearch in words:
        print("Found!")
    else:
        print("Not Found!")     

words_function()
```

And it outputs this order: ['Aardvark', 'coke', 'Desk', 'Zippy', 'zappy', 'Television', 'brothel', 'book', 'Dad', 'dog']

Which, last time I took English, wasn't alphabetical =p. What else do I need to add to my sort, or change, to make it come out in proper alphabetical order, ignoring if the word is lower case or capital, and just sorting in based on alphabetization?

Aardvark, book, brothel, coke, Dad, Desk, dog, Television, zappy, Zippy

Answer (score 12):

[`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) *returns* the sorted list. It does not modify the list in place. You'll have to store the sorted list somewhere

```
words = sorted(words, key=str.lower)
```

On python 2.6

```
>>> words= ['Aardvark', 'coke', 'Desk', 'Zippy', 'zappy', 'Television', 'brothel', 'book', 'Dad', 'dog']
>>> sorted(words,key=str.lower)
['Aardvark', 'book', 'brothel', 'coke', 'Dad', 'Desk', 'dog', 'Television', 'zappy', 'Zippy']
>>> words
['Aardvark', 'coke', 'Desk', 'Zippy', 'zappy', 'Television', 'brothel', 'book', 'Dad', 'dog']
>>> words = sorted(words,key=str.lower)
>>> words
['Aardvark', 'book', 'brothel', 'coke', 'Dad', 'Desk', 'dog', 'Television', 'zappy', 'Zippy']
```

Comment: This works! Thanks! =) I would upvote, but I'm too much of a noob, it won't let me.

Now...in my search function, can I make it so they can type "aardvark" and it will return Found, even though it isn't capitalized when they search for it?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified, I'm using 3.3.2, so the answer given by RedBaron works.

Comment: @user3093807 You can always upvote and accept ;). For case insensitive search convert both (the list and the word) to lowercase and then search `word_to_search.lower() in (x.lower() for x in words)`

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted(words, key=cmp_to_key(locale.strcoll))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use method (build-in list)

```
list.sort()
```

It sorts and changes list

Comment: This will not sort case-insensitively. `list.sort()` will put capital letters before lower case letters. `sorted(words, key=str.lower)` is superior in this regard, except that you do need to capture the output.

Answer (score 0):

sorted(words, key=str.lower)

***This will not change words assignment, words didn't change at this moment. but 'words.sort(key = str.lower)' change the assignment directly.***
    but it is funny that even you have sorted the list again. the list is not totally in alphabet order,

example.

words = ['Aardvark', 'coke', 'Desk', 'Zippy', 'zappy', 'Television', 'brothel', 'book', 'Dad', 'dog']

> > > sorted(words, key= str.lower)
> > >       ['Aardvark', 'book', 'brothel', 'coke', 'Dad', 'Desk', 'dog', 'Television', 'zappy', 'Zippy']

you can see 'dog' is after 'Desk'

another example.

words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'E', 'F', 'A', 'B', 'b', 'A']

words.sort(key = str.lower)

words

['a', 'A', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'E', 'F']

.sort(key=str.lower) is not means sort the values in regular alphabetical order properly.